# What are these <%$ %> asp.net markup tags called?

Tags: asp.net, syntax, markup

I was reading about how to work with SqlDataSource objects by adding properties in the markup, and for the ConnectionString property, the author used something like

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:lyric %>" ... >
```

The use of <%$ %> is new to me and the author didn't really explain it. I mean, I can see pretty easily what it does in this instance.

But, I want to learn the syntax inside <%$ %> to access other things inside Web Config. I don't know what this type of markup is called so I can't google it. I'm having a rough time finding it.

Do tags like <%@ %>, <%# %>, and <%$ %> have a special blanket name? (so I can learn other variations)
Is there a specific name for <%$ %>? (so I can look it up and learn the syntax)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called "ASP.NET inline expressions" or "ASP.NET inline code-blocks". You can learn more about them here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

<%$ ... %> is the syntax for an expression builder.

Comment: awesome resource. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for this! Weren't they also known by some other name?

Comment: I first ran across them as "ASP.NET inline code-blocks", but Microsoft apparently likes "ASP.NET inline expressions" instead. I've never heard of them by any other terms (although if someone else has, it would be nice to know what else they're called).